# Deploying to Firebase Hosting using CircleCI

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, firebase, circleci

I'm trying to figure out how to deploy to Firebase Hosting using CircleCI.  As far as I know, there is no way to setup deployment with an SSH key, so I'm trying to find a way of logging into Firebase during deployment and push the code.  What I have tried so far is the following in my circle.yml:

```
// circle.yml
deployment:
  production:
    branch: circle-deploy
    commands:
      - npm install -g firebase-tools
      - firebase login | echo -e "${FIREBASE_EMAIL}\n${FIREBASE_PASSWORD}"
      - firebase deploy
```

However, I keep getting the following error and I'm not sure how to remedy it.

```
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: write EPIPE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)
```

Answer (score 38):

I just had to do this and there is a easier way

1. On your machine, you can get your access token by typing

   ```
   firebase login:ci
   ```
2. Save that token as an environment variable in circleci, `$FIREBASE_TOKEN`
3. For your deploy step, you can skip the login:

   ```
   deployment:
     production:
       branch: master
       commands:
         - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
   ```

Comment: Had no idea `login:ci` was a thing. thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 16):

A small addition to the other answers above...

In order to avoid installing firebase-tools globally in circle ci on every build:

Modify your package.json file to include firebase-tools as a dev dependency like so:

```
npm install --save-dev firebase-tools
```

Then in your circle.yml file:

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - ./node_modules/.bin/firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this question, these are the steps I had to take to get CircleCI (and presumably any other CI) working with Firebase Hosting.

1. Generate a CI token: `firebase login:ci`
2. Save that token as an ENV var (`FIREBASE_TOKEN`)
3. Use the token in your deploy script: `firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive`

Firebase added the `login:ci` recently to prevent people from using personal deploy tokens for CI services.

Answer (score 3):

This is my initial setup, deploy only master, skip tests

1. run **npm install -g firebase-tools** on your local machine
2. run **firebase login:ci** to get the token on your local machine
3. run firebase init.  This will create firebase.json make sure it is committed
4. configure **FIREBASE_TOKEN** in Environment Variables in BUILD SETTINGS of the project on circileci

//circle.yml

```
general:
  branches:
    only:
      - master

test:
  override:
    - echo "test"

deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - npm install -g firebase-tools
      - firebase deploy --token=$FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the process we followed to deploy to CircleCi.

1. Store your username and password as environment variables at the project level in CircleCi.
2. Edit your circle.yml

   ```
   deployment:
     production:
       branch: your_branch
       commands:
         - npm install -g firebase-tools
         - firebase login --email $FIREBASE_USERNAME --password $FIREBASE_PASSWORD
         - firebase deploy
   ```
3. Push to your branch

Seems to work fine.